# Python Simulation Timer

Tags: python, timer

I'm looking for a way, in Python, to set up a "timer" for multiple agents.

My simulation is going to have many vehicles which will need to wait for independent time periods before performing actions.  However, I also want to be able to perform "stop" "start" and "reset" operations on the timer.

Any suggestions on what to use?

Comment: The threads would have to share a timer.  The issue is getting a controllable timer that can spread across threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use SimPy (https://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Probably rather the 2.3.1 version at the moment (although the SimPy3 should be a valid choice when finished).

There are many examples (https://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.1/Manuals/Examples.html), that seems to be similar to your case. I have used SimPy for simple biology-themed agent-based simulations myself and it worked well.